# How to scrape website that executes script on client side using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a site https://alfagift.id where it runs a fingerprint script
https://alfagift.id/_nuxt/f9d159c.js

```
__fpjs_d_m||Math.random()>=.001))try{var t=new XMLHttpRequest;t.open("get","https://m1.openfpcdn.io/fingerprintjs/v3.3.3/npm-monitoring",!0),t.send()}catch(t){console.error(t)}}(),[4,vt(r)];case 1:return t.sent(),[2,gt(L(ft,{debug:n},
```

The fingerprint is needed so that I can scrape other parts. I tried

```
resp=requests.get("https://alfagift.id/_nuxt/f9d159c.js")
resp.content
```

However it returns a function, no fingerprint is being returned.

The fingerprint is needed as seen here
[image]

So my question is how do you get the fingerprint value from the script using python requests?

Comment: Have you tried using the value from your own browser ? Apart from that, you are asking a very difficult question. Did you consider using a webscraping framework that may help you with this task ?

Comment: I want to try to generate new values at every scrape. It would be easier to try using selenium, however using requests will be faster.

Comment: Yes, but there is a Javascript protection against that. Try Selenium.

Comment: so there's just no way for requests to handle this sort JavaScript protection? I thought there might be a workaround around this limitation.

Comment: Either reverse-engineer the (obfuscated) Javascript code to be able to generate fingerprints in pure Python (probably very hard), use a library to run the Javascript for you (for example [py_mini_racer](https://pypi.org/project/py-mini-racer/)) and try to make it run with your fingerprint code (don't know if difficult or not), or just use Selenium (moderately easy).

Comment: Requests just sends requests (hence the name) to HTTP servers, and reads the answer. It is content-agnostic, it just provides a way to communicate over the HTTP protocol. What you do after the request was received is none of its business.

Comment: ok got it, thanks for the input will try using Selenium

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250234/discussion-between-hal-and-lenormju).